# SQL Server connection loss MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have Access databases that use a SQL Server backend. Is there a simple way to have Access detect if a connection to the SQL Server has been lost?

I tried having a column comparison from time stamps. That didn't work.

Desired result is when a SQL Server connection is lost to have Access display a message and automatically close.

Comment: Instead of trying to maintain a persistent connection why not open one only as and when it's needed?

Comment: These programs need to stay open all day. Our SQL servers have dropped connections and it confuses our employees. All they need to do is close and reopen. If I could get Access to do that automatically that would be better.

Comment: You should be looking at resolving **WHY** the connection is being lost, as this could cause problems if users are halfway through doing something.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help you to use a newer version of Microsoft Access (you didn't write which one you use) to let Microsoft Access reopen a lost connection without the need to restart it.

[Benefits of using Microsoft Access 2019 (Standard or 365)](https://www.software-matters.co.uk/microsoft-access-benefits-2019.html):

> 6. ODBC Connection Retry feature
>
> This applies to Access database systems which link to other types of data source – e.g. SQL Server. **In the past, if the connection to a data table was lost, the only way to re-gain it was to close the database and re-open it.** Fortunately this wasn’t a frequent occurrence! **Access will now attempt to re-open the connection itself, automatically, whenever you do something in the system that requires that connection.**

Answer (score 0):

Here are some vba code we use in house to detect if there is a connection to a back end linked table

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'Developer set parameters
Dim LinkedTables() As String
Dim LinkedFiles() As String
Dim ListGroups() As String
Dim LinkErrors As Boolean
Dim NumTables As Integer
Dim NumGroups As Integer


Private Sub AttachFile1_Click()
Dim i As Integer

If IsNull(Me.File1) Then
    MsgBox "You must enter in a valid data file.", vbExclamation
    GoTo Done
End If
For i = 1 To UBound(LinkedTables, 2)
    LinkedTables(4, i) = Me.File1
Next i
LinkErrors = False
DoCmd.Hourglass True
    For i = 1 To UBound(LinkedTables, 2)
        LinkedTables(3, i) = AttachTable(LinkedTables(0, i), 
  LinkedTables(4, i), LinkedTables(2, 1))
        If Len(LinkedTables(3, i)) > 0 Then LinkErrors = True
    Next i
DoCmd.Hourglass False
If LinkErrors = True Then
    Me.ViewTabs.Pages("List").Visible = False
    Me.ViewTabs.Pages("Errors").Visible = True
    Me.ViewTabs.Pages("Errors").SetFocus
    MsgBox ("There were errors attaching tables.")
Else
    MsgBox ("Attachments successfully made.")
    If Me.OpenArgs = "Startup" Then
       DoCmd.Close
       Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.ViewTabs.Pages("List").Visible = True
    Me.ViewTabs.Pages("Errors").Visible = False
    Me.listStatus.Requery
    Me.listStatus.SetFocus
End If


 Done:

 End Sub



 Private Sub Form_Open(cancel As Integer)
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
 Dim x As String
 Dim FileSaved As Boolean
 If Me.OpenArgs = "Startup" Then
   Me.Visible = False
   If LinkErrors = True Then
      Me.CompanyLabel.Caption = "There was an error connecting one or 
  more of the linked tables."
      Me.CompanyLabel.Visible = True
      Me.Visible = True
   Else
      DoCmd.Close
      DoCmd.OpenForm "xFirst Screen"
      Exit Sub
   End If
  End If

'Check to see if there are any linked tables
If NumTables = 0 Then
    'If not display message then goto OpenIfTableBased
    MsgBox ("There are no linked tables in this database.")
    DoCmd.Close
    GoTo Done
End If
'The links are checked by filling the listbox ListStatus and running the 
function GetLinkedTables
'If errors then display the errors page otherwise display the list page
If LinkErrors = True Then
    Me.ViewTabs.Pages("Errors").Visible = True
    Me.ViewTabs.Pages("List").Visible = False
Else
    Me.ViewTabs.Pages("Errors").Visible = False
    Me.ViewTabs.Pages("List").Visible = True
End If
'Determine if the attachments are table based
    'Not table based therefore determine if this is single, dual or 
multilocation
    ReDim LinkedFiles(0)
    LinkedFiles(0) = LinkedTables(1, 1)
    For i = 2 To NumTables
        FileSaved = False
        For j = 0 To UBound(LinkedFiles, 1)
            If LinkedTables(1, i) = LinkedFiles(j) Then
                FileSaved = True
            End If
        Next j
        If Not FileSaved = True Then
            ReDim Preserve LinkedFiles(UBound(LinkedFiles, 1) + 1)
            LinkedFiles(UBound(LinkedFiles, 1)) = LinkedTables(1, i)
        End If
    Next i
    Select Case UBound(LinkedFiles, 1)
        Case 0
            'Single file processing
            Me.SingleFile.Visible = True
            Me.File1 = LinkedFiles(0)
        Case Else
            'Multilocation processing
            MsgBox "There is more than one attached file.  Cannot 
   process."
            DoCmd.Close
            GoTo Done
   End Select
   
    If Me.OpenArgs = "Startup" And LinkErrors Then 
   Me.ViewTabs.Pages("SingleFile").SetFocus

   Done:

   End Sub


   Public Function GetLinkedTables()
   'Function fills the array LinkedTables
   Dim dbs As Database
   Dim tbd As TableDef
   Dim s As String
   Dim i As Integer

    i = 1
    ReDim LinkedTables(4, 0) As String
    LinkedTables(0, 0) = "Table Name"
    LinkedTables(1, 0) = "Attached File"
    LinkedTables(2, 0) = "Type"
     LinkedTables(3, 0) = "Error"
    LinkedTables(4, 0) = "New File"
    LinkErrors = False
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    For Each tbd In dbs.TableDefs
    If tbd.Connect <> "" And Left(tbd.Name, 1) <> "~" Then
        ReDim Preserve LinkedTables(4, i) As String
        LinkedTables(0, i) = tbd.Name
        LinkedTables(1, i) = Mid$(tbd.Connect, InStr(1, tbd.Connect, 
    "DATABASE=") + 9)
        LinkedTables(2, i) = Mid$(tbd.Connect, 1, InStr(tbd.Connect, ";") 
     - 1)
        If LinkedTables(2, i) = "" Then
            LinkedTables(2, i) = "Access"
         'if type is Access, then verify table name as test of table link
            On Error GoTo ErrorLink
                s = dbs.TableDefs(LinkedTables(0, i)).Fields(0).Name
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            LinkedTables(2, i) = Left(tbd.Connect, InStr(1, tbd.Connect, 
  "DATABASE=") - 1)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Next tbd
    GoTo Done

   ErrorLink:
   LinkedTables(3, i) = "Error in link"
   LinkErrors = True
   Resume Next
   Done:
   GetLinkedTables = i - 1
   NumTables = i - 1
   End Function



   Public Function FillList(fld As Control, ID, Row, col, Code)
   Dim ReturnVal
  'On Error GoTo FillListErrHandler
   ReturnVal = Null
   Select Case Code
   Case 0                                   'Initialize
   ReturnVal = GetLinkedTables
   Case 1                                   'Open
   ReturnVal = Timer
   Case 3                                   'Number of Rows
   ReturnVal = UBound(LinkedTables, 2) + 1
   Me.dispNumberAttachments = UBound(LinkedTables, 2) & " attached 
   tables."
    Case 4                                   'Number of Cols
     ReturnVal = 3
    Case 5                                   'Col Width
     ReturnVal = -1
     Case 6                                   'Record
     If Row > UBound(LinkedTables, 2) Then
      ReturnVal = Null
       Else
      ReturnVal = LinkedTables(col, Row)
      End If
      End Select
      FillList = ReturnVal
      GoTo Done
      FillListErrHandler:
      FillList = Null
      Done:

      End Function



      Public Function FillErrorList(fld As Control, ID, Row, col, Code)
      Dim ReturnVal
      'On Error GoTo FillErrorListErrHandler
       ReturnVal = Null
      Select Case Code
      Case 0                                   'Initialize
      ReturnVal = True
       Case 1                                   'Open
       ReturnVal = Timer
       Case 3                                   'Number of Rows
       ReturnVal = UBound(LinkedTables, 2) + 1
       Case 4                                   'Number of Cols
       ReturnVal = 2
       Case 5                                   'Col Width
       ReturnVal = -1
       Case 6                                   'Record
       If Row > UBound(LinkedTables, 2) Then
        ReturnVal = Null
       Else
       If col = 0 Then ReturnVal = LinkedTables(0, Row)
       If col = 1 Then ReturnVal = LinkedTables(3, Row)
       End If
       End Select
       FillErrorList = ReturnVal
       GoTo Done
       FillErrorListErrHandler:
       FillErrorList = Null
       Done:

       End Function



        Private Sub Form_Unload(cancel As Integer)
        Dim answer, msg As String
        If Me.OpenArgs = "Startup" Then
        If LinkErrors = True Then
        msg = "There are errors with your linked tables." & vbCrLf & "Are 
         you sure you want to exit?"
        answer = MsgBox(msg, vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Check Writer - 
         Attachment Manager")
          If answer = 6 Then
           DoCmd.Quit
          Else
          cancel = True
          End If
          Else
          DoCmd.OpenForm "xFirst Screen"
          End If
          End If
          End Sub


           Private Sub listStatus_DblClick(cancel As Integer)
           MsgBox "Table = " & Me.listStatus.Column(0) & vbCrLf & _
           "File = " & Me.listStatus.Column(1) & vbCrLf & _
           "Type = " & Me.listStatus.Column(2)
           End Sub


            Private Sub selFile1_Click()
            Dim lngFlags As Long
            Dim gfni As adh_accOfficeGetFileNameInfo

            'On Error GoTo HandleErrors

             With gfni
            .lngFlags = lngFlags
            .strFilter = "MDB Files (*.mdb)"
            .lngFilterIndex = CInt("1")
            .strFile = ""
            .strDlgTitle = "Select datafile"
            .strOpenTitle = "Select"
             .strFile = ""
             .strInitialDir = ""
              End With
             If adhOfficeGetFileName(gfni, True) = adhcAccErrSuccess Then
             Me.File1 = Trim(gfni.strFile)
             End If

              ExitHere:
              Exit Sub

              HandleErrors:
             MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & ")"
             Resume ExitHere

             End Sub



             Function AttachTable(strTable As String, strPath As String, 
              strType As String) As String
              Dim dbs As Database
              Dim tdf As TableDef
              Dim fld As Field
              Dim strPrefix As String
              Dim strNewConnect As String

               On Error GoTo Errorhandler
               Set dbs = CurrentDb()
              Select Case Left(strType, 5)
              Case "Acces"
              strPrefix = ";DATABASE="
              strNewConnect = strPrefix & strPath
              Case "dBase"
              strPrefix = strType & "DATABASE="
              strNewConnect = strPrefix & GetPathPart(strPath) & 
              ";TABLE=" & strTable & "#DBF"
              Case Else
              strPrefix = strType & "DATABASE="
              strNewConnect = strPrefix & strPath
              End Select
              Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs(strTable)
              ExistingTable:
              tdf.Connect = strNewConnect
              tdf.RefreshLink
              AttachTable = ""
              GoTo Done

              NewTable:
              Set tdf = dbs.CreateTableDef(strTable)
              tdf.Connect = strNewConnect
              tdf.SourceTableName = strTable
              dbs.TableDefs.Append tdf
              tdf.RefreshLink
              AttachTable = ""
              GoTo Done

              Errorhandler:  
              Select Case Err.Number
              Case 3011
               AttachTable = "Could not find the table " & strTable & " 
               in " & strPath
               Case 3265
              'Table not in table definitions
               Resume NewTable
               Case Else
               AttachTable = Err.Description
               End Select

               Done:
               dbs.Close
               End Function




                Function GetPathPart(strPath As String) As String
                Dim i As Integer

                For i = Len(strPath) To 1 Step -1
                If Mid$(strPath, i, 1) = "\" Then Exit For
                Next i
                GetPathPart = Left$(strPath, i)

                End Function



                 Private Sub Command98_Click()
                 On Error GoTo Err_Command98_Click


                 If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
                 DoCmd.Close

                 Exit_Command98_Click:
                 Exit Sub

                 Err_Command98_Click:
                 MsgBox Err.Description
                 Resume Exit_Command98_Click

                 End Sub
```

[image]